# Using an immutable or mutable object in this java context?

Tags: java, immutability, mutable

I have a class `Account` with many fields and only the field `status` (active or inactive) may change in the object.
So we are talking about a class with 10 fields with only the field `status` that actually would make sense to have setters.

What would you do in this scenario, would you make the whole class immutable besides that particular field which changes status?

Comment: There is no such thing as a *partially* immutable class; the class is *mutable* if any of the fields are modifiable. I don't see the purpose in adding mutators you don't need, but what is your actual question?

Comment: There's not enough detail in the question for anyone to be able to provide a useful analysis of the situation.  But an object with even one mutable field is not an immutable object.

Comment: @Elliot Frisch that the status of Account may change where as begin date, name, last name etc.. will never change. Since I have billions of accounts, creating a newly object for each time the status changes from active to inactive for each Account, will be expensive

Comment: Keep status out of the immutable and use the immutable object as key to the status?

Comment: @ThomasChristensen in other words?

Comment: It was more of an abstract thought. But if you keep the object entirely immutable you could use it as key in a map that stores the `status`. I don't know though if your immutable's identity will be based in its field values or you could have multiple immutables with same field values and not consider them `equal`.

Answer (score 0):

`Account` need not be immutable, but its composed classes as fields if any would be immutable.
Plus, yes only `status` will have setter method.

Something like below -

```
class Account {
    private int a;
    private String b;
    private SomeClass s; //Make this immutable
    private String status;

    String setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the immutable fields `final`?

Comment: yes that can be done. Infact why just immutable fields. why not every field except status.

Comment: That's what I meant, yes.